# Why am I getting a Segmentation Fault error C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, realloc

I am trying to write a function to take words from a text file, and store them in dynamic memory. The text file is structured with one word on each line, I can read the words in fine, but after the 4th iteration I get a segmentation error. I don't understand, because I am using realloc, so in theory the program should just reallocate space as i need it.

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    char** dictionaryOfWords = NULL;
    int numberOfWords = 0;
    char* word;
    //fp = fopen("/etc/motd", "r");
    fp = fopen("words.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    //This reads in a line from an external file
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        //Prints the characters in the line and the length of the line
        printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", read);
        printf("%s", line);
        //slength just returns the length of the word without the ending character (/n)
        word = malloc(slength(line));
        //returnWord returns the string passed in without the ending character (/n)
        word = returnWord(line);
        printf("test 1\n");
        if(numberOfWords == 0){
            dictionaryOfWords = malloc(1);
            printf("allocated space for pointer to first word\n");
            dictionaryOfWords[numberOfWords] = malloc(len);
            printf("allocated space for first word\n");
            strcpy(dictionaryOfWords[numberOfWords], word);
            printf("copied word into memory\n");
        }else{
            dictionaryOfWords = realloc(dictionaryOfWords, numberOfWords + 1);
            printf("allocated space for pointer to word\n");
            dictionaryOfWords[numberOfWords] = realloc(dictionaryOfWords[numberOfWords], len);
            printf("allocated space for first word\n");
            strcat(dictionaryOfWords[numberOfWords], word);
        }
        numberOfWords++;
        free(line);
        free(word);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Comment: It isn't clear why you allocate some memory with `word = malloc(slength(line));` and immediately overwrite the pointer with `word = returnWord(line);`.

Comment: You have `char** dictionaryOfWords = NULL;` and then `dictionaryOfWords = malloc(1);` and then `dictionaryOfWords[numberOfWords] = malloc(len);` so you have buffer overflow. 1 byte is not enough to hold a pointer.

Comment: HInt: `malloc(1)` is completely and utterly useless in nearly every invocation ever. "allocated space for pointer to first word" is a lie. You allocated one byte. `sizeof(char*)` is *considerably* larger.

Comment: Tip: Use `calloc()` which forces you to explain your thinking in terms of elements and size of each element.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things wrong here

1. The code below allocated memory of size `slength(line)` then, you reassign `word` causing the pointer to the original memory to be lost, hence causing a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) in the program.

```
word = malloc(slength(line));
word = returnWord(line);
```

2. The code below allocates 1 byte of memory which is incorrect considering the type of `dictionaryOfWords` which is `char**`.

```
dictionaryOfWords = malloc(1);
```

Assuming you want to make a array of strings the correct way would be:

`char **dictionaryOfWords = malloc(sizeof(char *) * n);`

3. The code below allocates memory for the `numberOfWords` element of `dictionaryOfWords`. This is also incorrect since the type is not compatible with the memory you are allocating. This also causes a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) since `malloc()` returns a pointer and the 1 byte you allocated earlier is not enough to store a pointer.

`dictionaryOfWords[numberOfWords] = malloc(len);`

4. Since the code above has messed up the program already, using `strcpy` on a incorrect initialized segment of memory will further cause issues.

`strcpy(dictionaryOfWords[numberOfWords], word);`